# Web will not compile when declaring RouterExtensions in components constructor

Tags: nativescript-angular

When I add `private routerExtensions: RouterExtensions` to my home components constructor web compilation fails while ios still builds and runs fine. I've worked in angular projects before but not nativescript-angular so I'm not sure if I'm missing something, tried a lot of googling but most people have an issue with the actual import which this compiles fine with the import just not the constructor part.

Home Component

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterExtensions } from 'nativescript-angular/router';
import { AccountService } from '../shared/services/account/account.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css'],
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  public loggedIn = false;
  public title = '';

  constructor(private routerExtensions: RouterExtensions, private accountService: AccountService) {
    this.loggedIn = accountService.isLoggedIn;
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  login() {
    console.log('login');
    this.loggedIn = true;
  }

  logout() {
    console.log('logout');
    this.loggedIn = false;
  }
}
```

Error:

```
Date: 2019-08-06T00:25:17.513Z
Hash: eeee77338516ca2739c3
Time: 7971ms
chunk {main} main.js, main.js.map (main) 24 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {polyfills} polyfills.js, polyfills.js.map (polyfills) 274 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {runtime} runtime.js, runtime.js.map (runtime) 6.08 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {styles} styles.js, styles.js.map (styles) 16.3 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {vendor} vendor.js, vendor.js.map (vendor) 4.4 MB [initial] [rendered]

WARNING in ./node_modules/nativescript-angular/element-registry.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'tns-core-modules/ui/bottom-navigation' in '/Users/chrishaen/Full Stack/web/web/node_modules/nativescript-angular'

WARNING in ./node_modules/nativescript-angular/element-registry.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'tns-core-modules/ui/tab-navigation-base/tab-content-item' in '/Users/chrishaen/Full Stack/web/web/node_modules/nativescript-angular'

WARNING in ./node_modules/nativescript-angular/element-registry.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'tns-core-modules/ui/tabs' in '/Users/chrishaen/Full Stack/web/web/node_modules/nativescript-angular'

ERROR in ./node_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/tab-navigation-base/tab-strip/tab-strip.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../../../color' in '/Users/chrishaen/Full Stack/web/web/node_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/tab-navigation-base/tab-strip'
ERROR in ./node_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/builder/component-builder/component-builder.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../../../platform' in '/Users/chrishaen/Full Stack/web/web/node_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/builder/component-builder'
ERROR in ./node_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/core/bindable/bindable.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../../../utils/utils' in '/Users/chrishaen/Full Stack/web/web/node_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/core/bindable'
ERROR in ./node_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/tab-navigation-base/tab-strip/tab-strip.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../../core/view' in '/Users/chrishaen/Full Stack/web/web/node_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/tab-navigation-base/tab-strip'
ERROR in ./node_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/tab-navigation-base/tab-strip-item/tab-strip-item.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../../core/view' in '/Users/chrishaen/Full Stack/web/web/node_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/tab-navigation-base/tab-strip-item'
ERROR in ./node_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/builder/builder.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../../platform' in '/Users/chrishaen/Full Stack/web/web/node_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/builder'
ERROR in ./node_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/tab-navigation-base/tab-strip/tab-strip.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../../text-base' in '/Users/chrishaen/Full Stack/web/web/node_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/tab-navigation-base/tab-strip'
ERROR in ./node_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/tab-navigation-base/tab-strip-item/tab-strip-item.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../../text-base' in '/Users/chrishaen/Full Stack/web/web/node_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/tab-navigation-base/tab-strip-item'
ERROR in ./node_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/content-view/content-view.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../core/view' in '/Users/chrishaen/Full Stack/web/web/node_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/content-view'
ERROR in ./node_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/placeholder/placeholder.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../core/view' in '/Users/chrishaen/Full Stack/web/web/node_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/placeholder'
ERROR in ./node_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/repeater/repeater.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../label' in '/Users/chrishaen/Full Stack/web/web/node_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/repeater'
ERROR in ./node_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/proxy-view-container/proxy-view-container.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../layouts/layout-base' in '/Users/chrishaen/Full Stack/web/web/node_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/proxy-view-container'
ERROR in ./node_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/repeater/repeater.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../layouts/layout-base' in '/Users/chrishaen/Full Stack/web/web/node_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/repeater'
ERROR in ./node_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/repeater/repeater.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../layouts/stack-layout' in '/Users/chrishaen/Full Stack/web/web/node_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/repeater'
ERROR in ./node_modules/tns-core-modules/utils/debug.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../platform' in '/Users/chrishaen/Full Stack/web/web/node_modules/tns-core-modules/utils'
ERROR in ./node_modules/tns-core-modules/module-name-resolver/module-name-resolver.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../platform/platform' in '/Users/chrishaen/Full Stack/web/web/node_modules/tns-core-modules/module-name-resolver'
ERROR in ./node_modules/tns-core-modules/text/formatted-string.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../ui/core/view' in '/Users/chrishaen/Full Stack/web/web/node_modules/tns-core-modules/text'
ERROR in ./node_modules/tns-core-modules/text/span.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../ui/core/view' in '/Users/chrishaen/Full Stack/web/web/node_modules/tns-core-modules/text'
ERROR in ./node_modules/tns-core-modules/file-system/file-system.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './file-system-access' in '/Users/chrishaen/Full Stack/web/web/node_modules/tns-core-modules/file-system'
ERROR in ./node_modules/tns-core-modules/js-libs/polymer-expressions/polymer-expressions.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'js-libs/esprima' in '/Users/chrishaen/Full Stack/web/web/node_modules/tns-core-modules/js-libs/polymer-expressions'
ERROR in ./node_modules/tns-core-modules/js-libs/polymer-expressions/polymer-expressions.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'js-libs/polymer-expressions/path-parser' in '/Users/chrishaen/Full Stack/web/web/node_modules/tns-core-modules/js-libs/polymer-expressions'
ERROR in ./node_modules/tns-core-modules/file-system/file-system.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'platform' in '/Users/chrishaen/Full Stack/web/web/node_modules/tns-core-modules/file-system'
ERROR in ./node_modules/nativescript-angular/platform-providers.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'tns-core-modules/platform' in '/Users/chrishaen/Full Stack/web/web/node_modules/nativescript-angular'
ERROR in ./node_modules/nativescript-angular/view-util.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'tns-core-modules/platform' in '/Users/chrishaen/Full Stack/web/web/node_modules/nativescript-angular'
ERROR in ./node_modules/nativescript-angular/directives/platform-filters.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'tns-core-modules/platform' in '/Users/chrishaen/Full Stack/web/web/node_modules/nativescript-angular/directives'
ERROR in ./node_modules/nativescript-angular/directives/action-bar.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'tns-core-modules/ui/action-bar' in '/Users/chrishaen/Full Stack/web/web/node_modules/nativescript-angular/directives'
ERROR in ./node_modules/nativescript-angular/element-registry.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'tns-core-modules/ui/activity-indicator' in '/Users/chrishaen/Full Stack/web/web/node_modules/nativescript-angular'
ERROR in ./node_modules/nativescript-angular/element-registry.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'tns-core-modules/ui/button' in '/Users/chrishaen/Full Stack/web/web/node_modules/nativescript-angular'
ERROR in ./node_modules/nativescript-angular/element-registry.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'tns-core-modules/ui/core/view' in '/Users/chrishaen/Full Stack/web/web/node_modules/nativescript-angular'
ERROR in ./node_modules/nativescript-angular/view-util.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'tns-core-modules/ui/core/view' in '/Users/chrishaen/Full Stack/web/web/node_modules/nativescript-angular'
ERROR in ./node_modules/nativescript-angular/element-registry.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'tns-core-modules/ui/date-picker' in '/Users/chrishaen/Full Stack/web/web/node_modules/nativescript-angular'
ERROR in ./node_modules/nativescript-angular/element-registry.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'tns-core-modules/ui/frame' in '/Users/chrishaen/Full Stack/web/web/node_modules/nativescript-angular'
ERROR in ./node_modules/nativescript-angular/platform-providers.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'tns-core-modules/ui/frame' in '/Users/chrishaen/Full Stack/web/web/node_modules/nativescript-angular'
ERROR in ./node_modules/nativescript-angular/directives/dialogs.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'tns-core-modules/ui/frame' in '/Users/chrishaen/Full Stack/web/web/node_modules/nativescript-angular/directives'
ERROR in ./node_modules/nativescript-angular/router/page-router-outlet.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'tns-core-modules/ui/frame' in '/Users/chrishaen/Full Stack/web/web/node_modules/nativescript-angular/router'
ERROR in ./node_modules/nativescript-angular/element-registry.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'tns-core-modules/ui/html-view' in '/Users/chrishaen/Full Stack/web/web/node_modules/nativescript-angular'
ERROR in ./node_modules/nativescript-angular/element-registry.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'tns-core-modules/ui/image' in '/Users/chrishaen/Full Stack/web/web/node_modules/nativescript-angular'
ERROR in ./node_modules/nativescript-angular/element-registry.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'tns-core-modules/ui/label' in '/Users/chrishaen/Full Stack/web/web/node_modules/nativescript-angular'
ERROR in ./node_modules/nativescript-angular/element-registry.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'tns-core-modules/ui/layouts/absolute-layout' in '/Users/chrishaen/Full Stack/web/web/node_modules/nativescript-angular'
ERROR in ./node_modules/nativescript-angular/element-registry.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'tns-core-modules/ui/layouts/dock-layout' in '/Users/chrishaen/Full Stack/web/web/node_modules/nativescript-angular'
ERROR in ./node_modules/nativescript-angular/element-registry.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'tns-core-modules/ui/layouts/flexbox-layout' in '/Users/chrishaen/Full Stack/web/web/node_modules/nativescript-angular'
ERROR in ./node_modules/nativescript-angular/app-host-view.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'tns-core-modules/ui/layouts/grid-layout' in '/Users/chrishaen/Full Stack/web/web/node_modules/nativescript-angular'
ERROR in ./node_modules/nativescript-angular/element-registry.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'tns-core-modules/ui/layouts/grid-layout' in '/Users/chrishaen/Full Stack/web/web/node_modules/nativescript-angular'
ERROR in ./node_modules/nativescript-angular/view-util.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'tns-core-modules/ui/layouts/layout-base' in '/Users/chrishaen/Full Stack/web/web/node_modules/nativescript-angular'
ERROR in ./node_modules/nativescript-angular/element-registry.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'tns-core-modules/ui/layouts/layout-base' in '/Users/chrishaen/Full Stack/web/web/node_modules/nativescript-angular'
ERROR in ./node_modules/nativescript-angular/directives/templated-items-comp.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'tns-core-modules/ui/layouts/layout-base' in '/Users/chrishaen/Full Stack/web/web/node_modules/nativescript-angular/directives'
ERROR in ./node_modules/nativescript-angular/element-registry.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'tns-core-modules/ui/layouts/stack-layout' in '/Users/chrishaen/Full Stack/web/web/node_modules/nativescript-angular'
ERROR in ./node_modules/nativescript-angular/element-registry.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'tns-core-modules/ui/layouts/wrap-layout' in '/Users/chrishaen/Full Stack/web/web/node_modules/nativescript-angular'
ERROR in ./node_modules/nativescript-angular/element-registry.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'tns-core-modules/ui/list-picker' in '/Users/chrishaen/Full Stack/web/web/node_modules/nativescript-angular'
ERROR in ./node_modules/nativescript-angular/element-registry.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'tns-core-modules/ui/list-view' in '/Users/chrishaen/Full Stack/web/web/node_modules/nativescript-angular'
ERROR in ./node_modules/nativescript-angular/element-registry.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'tns-core-modules/ui/page' in '/Users/chrishaen/Full Stack/web/web/node_modules/nativescript-angular'
ERROR in ./node_modules/nativescript-angular/platform-providers.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'tns-core-modules/ui/page' in '/Users/chrishaen/Full Stack/web/web/node_modules/nativescript-angular'
ERROR in ./node_modules/nativescript-angular/directives/action-bar.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'tns-core-modules/ui/page' in '/Users/chrishaen/Full Stack/web/web/node_modules/nativescript-angular/directives'
ERROR in ./node_modules/nativescript-angular/router/ns-empty-outlet.component.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'tns-core-modules/ui/page' in '/Users/chrishaen/Full Stack/web/web/node_modules/nativescript-angular/router'
ERROR in ./node_modules/nativescript-angular/router/page-router-outlet.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'tns-core-modules/ui/page' in '/Users/chrishaen/Full Stack/web/web/node_modules/nativescript-angular/router'
ERROR in ./node_modules/nativescript-angular/element-registry.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'tns-core-modules/ui/progress' in '/Users/chrishaen/Full Stack/web/web/node_modules/nativescript-angular'
ERROR in ./node_modules/nativescript-angular/element-registry.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'tns-core-modules/ui/scroll-view' in '/Users/chrishaen/Full Stack/web/web/node_modules/nativescript-angular'
ERROR in ./node_modules/nativescript-angular/element-registry.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'tns-core-modules/ui/search-bar' in '/Users/chrishaen/Full Stack/web/web/node_modules/nativescript-angular'
ERROR in ./node_modules/nativescript-angular/element-registry.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'tns-core-modules/ui/segmented-bar' in '/Users/chrishaen/Full Stack/web/web/node_modules/nativescript-angular'
ERROR in ./node_modules/nativescript-angular/element-registry.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'tns-core-modules/ui/slider' in '/Users/chrishaen/Full Stack/web/web/node_modules/nativescript-angular'
ERROR in ./node_modules/nativescript-angular/element-registry.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'tns-core-modules/ui/switch' in '/Users/chrishaen/Full Stack/web/web/node_modules/nativescript-angular'
ERROR in ./node_modules/nativescript-angular/element-registry.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'tns-core-modules/ui/tab-view' in '/Users/chrishaen/Full Stack/web/web/node_modules/nativescript-angular'
ERROR in ./node_modules/nativescript-angular/directives/tab-view.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'tns-core-modules/ui/tab-view' in '/Users/chrishaen/Full Stack/web/web/node_modules/nativescript-angular/directives'
ERROR in ./node_modules/nativescript-angular/element-registry.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'tns-core-modules/ui/text-field' in '/Users/chrishaen/Full Stack/web/web/node_modules/nativescript-angular'
ERROR in ./node_modules/nativescript-angular/element-registry.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'tns-core-modules/ui/text-view' in '/Users/chrishaen/Full Stack/web/web/node_modules/nativescript-angular'
ERROR in ./node_modules/nativescript-angular/element-registry.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'tns-core-modules/ui/time-picker' in '/Users/chrishaen/Full Stack/web/web/node_modules/nativescript-angular'
ERROR in ./node_modules/nativescript-angular/element-registry.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'tns-core-modules/ui/web-view' in '/Users/chrishaen/Full Stack/web/web/node_modules/nativescript-angular'
ERROR in ./node_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/builder/component-builder/component-builder.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'utils/debug' in '/Users/chrishaen/Full Stack/web/web/node_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/builder/component-builder'
** Angular Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open your browser on http://localhost:4200/ **
ℹ ｢wdm｣: Failed to compile.
```

Comment: I think your mixing `nativescript`-only modules with web modules. Just to be clear `RouterExtensions` work only on Nativescript, for web you use normal `Router` which you import from '@angular/router'

Comment: Your trying to do code sharing, right?

Comment: https://docs.nativescript.org/angular/core-concepts/angular-navigation

Comment: Yea according to the documentation this extends the angular router and adds some mobile functionality

Comment: Yes, it adds more functions... But those functions are not compatible with web apps, just with Nativescript apps.
What I am understanding is that you are trying to compile for web and not for Nativescript... Am I right?

Comment: I just tried out using the angular router instead and it works just fine. Thanks!

Comment: I am compiling for web, android, and ios using the nativscript-angular code-sharing, after rereading that documentation, you were right I would need a nativscript specific file to use routerextensions but angulars router does what I need it to do so I'll just use that

Comment: There you go....!!! Great to see you got it. You're right, you need separate files if you're using "Nativescript specific" or "web specific" functions.